# How do I use date-fns with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, date-fns

I have an ASP.NET Core website with TypeScript. My ASP.NET Core setup is typical in that it has a `node_modules` folder in the root of the project and then I copy the source folders of the libraries I'm using from `node_modules` to `wwwroot/lib` using Gulp.

Therefore, I have date-fns source files in `wwwroot/lib/date-fns` and in my TypeScript `.ts` file I'm trying to import it like this:

```
import * as fns from "lib/date-fns/i.am.stuck.here.js";
```

The VS2019 code editor is autocompleting the folder so it can see it, but I don't know what `.js` file to enter, it doesn't suggest one.

I also don't know if I should import * or something else. I'm not a frontend dev so I struggle with TS and JS and imports and requires and all that stuff.

I can see that date-fns has a typings file so I assume this is straight forward for those in the know.

---

Update:

I found this:

https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/examples/typescript/example.ts

Which is strange because updating my code to the below, which is auto-suggested as the editor reads the folders on disk:

```
import { format } from "lib/date-fns";
```

Leaves me with an error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lib/date-fns' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

When I was importing moment.js I pointed it at the `.js` file itself, which was auto-suggested.

Also, if I change to `'lib/date-not-exist'` I get the same error, so I'm unable to tell if it's a file path existence issue or a TypeScript locating module issue.

---

Update:

I can get TypeScript to squelch the error and presumably find a module with this:

```
import * as dformat from "lib/date-fns/format/index";
```

But this doesn't work because:

```
var result = dformat(date, 'dd.MM.yyy HH:mm:ss');
```

Gives error:

```
error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer in [Import a JavaScript module or library into TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67842286/import-a-javascript-module-or-library-into-typescript) if you're having problems importing modules generally using TypeScript and JavaScript in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the date-fns package from NPM using

```
npm install --save date-fns
```